# Eclipse IDE's Java Build Path has changed. Which do i choose?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, java-9

I am trying to follow some tutorials on Selenium, but get stumped at this point. 
Right-click on "project" and select Properties.
On the Properties dialog, click on "Java Build Path".
Click on the Libraries tab, and then
Click on "Add External JARs..

The Add External JARS button is grayed out, and disabled.
The dialog shows Modulepath and Classpath. 
If I pick either of these, the buttons are enabled.
The question is, which one do I pick? 
I am trying to add the selenium WebDriver's into Java Build Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select ***Classpath*** for the previous/legacy behavior.

*Modulepath* is for modular Java 9 applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select Java SE 1.8 while creating project.