# Can't add to libraries (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: eclipse

Some clients of mine are getting this on their Eclipse:

[image: image 1]
.

Rather than this:

[image: image 2]
.

Notice that the second image allows you to add external jars (what I need), though the first Eclipse seems to not have this option. How can I instruct them to get it as in the second picture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE's Java Build Path has changed. Which do i choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755854/eclipse-ides-java-build-path-has-changed-which-do-i-choose)

Answer (score 0):

This is Eclipse Oxygen's support for Java 9 modules.

Just click on the 'Classpath' entry to enable the buttons to add jars to the traditional class path.

Click on 'Modulepath' to add to the module path (if the jars have been set up to be modules).