# Impossible to add libraries in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, junit

I am trying to install a library for a class to run JUnit 4 and I am unable to as [everything is grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iGxU.png). I made sure to update my Eclipse on Mac and still nothing. Another person in my class has the same Mac and it works perfectly fine for them. 
Any idea, how I can install the libraries?

Comment: Select `Classpath` first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE's Java Build Path has changed. Which do i choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755854/eclipse-ides-java-build-path-has-changed-which-do-i-choose)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, I think when you would go to the "Java Build Path" the option to "Add external Jars" is disabled under "Libraries" and you might be seeing two or more options already placed in there (one being "classpath").
If that's the case then select "classpath" and then the button will get enabled and you'll be able to add your "JARs".